# showing loader image with submition using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#registration_form').on('submit',function(e){

     /// e.preventDefault();
     $("#loading").show();
      var email = $('#email').val();
      var checkEmail = $("#email").val().indexOf('@');
      var checkEmailDot = $("#email").val().indexOf('.');

    if(email == ''){
      $("#email").addClass('error');
      error_flag = 1; 
    }

    if(checkEmail<3 || checkEmailDot<9){
     $("#email").addClass('error');
     error_flag = 1;  
   }

      $.ajax({

         url: "<?=base_url('controller/registration_ajax')?>",
         // url: "<?=base_url('controller/register')?>",
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "JSON",
        data: {email: email},
        success: function(res){
          var data = $.parseJSON(res);
          var status = data.status;
          var message = data.message;
          if(status == 'true'){
            // $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            $('#message').html('');
            $('#message').html(message);
            $('#message').css('color',"green");
            $("loading").hide();
          }
          else{
            $('#message').html('');
            $('#message').html(message);
            $('#message').css('color',"red");
          }
        }
      });
     e.preventDefault();
    });
  });


how to use loader with ajax when message is success the load stop when message is or error loader is stop  how to use loader image image in this stiuation. if submition is true loading hide if false loading also hide.
```

how to use loader with ajax when message is success the load stop when message is or error loader is stop  how to use loader image image in this stiuation. if submition is true loading hide if false loading also hide.

Comment: What's your problem ? ``$("loading").hide();`` is missing the ``#`` maybe ?

Comment: this problem is it also shown in empty submition just click the submit button other problem resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `always` handler to do that.

Also note that, you should so the `loader` only if the ajax is sent, so in your case only after the validations are done it should be done.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#registration_form').on('submit', function(e) {

    /// e.preventDefault();    
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var checkEmail = $("#email").val().indexOf('@');
    var checkEmailDot = $("#email").val().indexOf('.');

    if (email == '') {
      $("#email").addClass('error');
      error_flag = 1;
    }

    if (checkEmail < 3 || checkEmailDot < 9) {
      $("#email").addClass('error');
      error_flag = 1;
    }

    $.ajax({
      url: "<?=base_url('controller/registration_ajax')?>",
      // url: "<?=base_url('controller/register')?>",
      type: "POST",
      datatype: "JSON",
      data: {
        email: email
      },
      beforeSend: function() {
        //show it only if the request is sent
        $("#loading").show();
      },
      success: function(res) {
        var data = $.parseJSON(res);
        var status = data.status;
        var message = data.message;
        if (status == 'true') {
          // $('#myModal').modal('hide');
          $('#message').html('');
          $('#message').html(message);
          $('#message').css('color', "green");
          $("loading").hide();
        } else {
          $('#message').html('');
          $('#message').html(message);
          $('#message').css('color', "red");
        }
      }
    }).always(function() {
      //irrespective of success/error hide it
      $("#loading").hide();
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: He has a basic mistake. Forgot the `#` in the selector. `:P`

Comment: thanx dear but the loader image is show on empty submittion also

Answer (score 0):

Have a loading image like this:

```
<img src="loader.gif" id="loader" />
```

And in the script, before the AJAX call, show it:

```
$("#loader").fadeIn(); // You can also use `.show()`
$.ajax({
  // all your AJAX stuff.
  // Inside the success function.
  success: function (res) {
    // all other stuff.
    // hide the image
    $("#loader").fadeOut(); // You can also use `.hide()`
  } // End success
}); // End AJAX
```

**Solution to your Problem**

You are missing `#` in your call:

```
$("loading").hide();
//-^ Add a # here.
```

Change it to:

```
$("#loading").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way:

```
function loadsth(){
    $('#load_dialog').show();
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "?ajax=ajax_request",
        data: { data:"test"},
        success:function(data) {
            $('#load_dialog').hide();
            }
        });         
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using jquery's ajax function  `beforeSend`

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/url",
    data: { data:"test"},
    beforeSend: function() {
        //SHOW YOUR LOADER
    },
    success:function(data) {
        //HIDE YOUR LOADER
        }
    });         
});
```

I hope this has given you some idea.

Answer (score 0):

try this its work for u

```
$.ajax({
       url: "<?=base_url('controller/registration_ajax')?>",
       type: 'POST',
          beforeSend: function(){
            $("#loaderDiv").show();
        },
       success: function(data) {
            $('#output-json-inbox').jJsonViewer(data);
            $("#loaderDiv").hide();

       },          
       error: function() {
        alert("error");
       }
    });
```